# How to make oauth_signature_method?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth

I have code like this :

```
let headers = [
        "Authorization": "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=****,oauth_token=******,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,oauth_timestamp=1493351401,oauth_nonce=KXTM16,oauth_version=1.0,oauth_signature=I*******",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]
```

But this code I got from Postman. How to make code in swift to get oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp and etc without copy paste from Postman ?

Comment: what you want to elaborate more ?

Comment: check this objective c thread : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28259667/3901620

Comment: KKRock : my code is manually from postman. i want build signature method from my program

Comment: how about swift?

Comment: you need to convert this code in swift or you can use this code using create  bridging Header file

Comment: ya i need to convert sir, how to convert it ?